# StringIndexOutofBoundsException when trying to setBackgroundColor using a variable inside a Adapter

Tags: java, android

When I try to place a String variable, with hexadecimal color inside to set the `setbackgroundcolor(Color.parseColor(String s))` of a edittext on my adapter class, it says

> StringIndexOutofBoundsException, length = 0, index = 0.

When I insert the String inside the `parseColor` by hand, for example `parseColor("#ffffff");`, It works!

My Adapter Class:

```
public class TasksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tasks> {
    private Context sContext;
    private List<Tasks> taskData = new ArrayList<>();
    public TasksAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @SuppressLint("SupportAnnotationUsage") @LayoutRes ArrayList<Tasks> list){
        super(context, 0, list);
        sContext = context;
        taskData = list;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
        View listItem = convertView;
        if(listItem == null)
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(sContext).inflate(R.layout.item_tasks, parent,false);
        final Tasks presenteTask = taskData.get(position);
        TextView taskTitle = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tasksTitle);
        taskTitle.setText(presenteTask.getTitle());
        EditText taskColor = (EditText) listItem.findViewById(R.id.taskColor);
        taskColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(presenteTask.getHexaColor()));
        return listItem;
    }
}
```

The error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.mylcm, PID: 672
>       java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>           at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:1384)
>           at com.example.mylcm.Utils.Adapters.TasksAdapter.getView(TasksAdapter.java:49)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2365)
>           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:847)
>           at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1826)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2164)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1780)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1546)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:761)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2496)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2212)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: I would guess that presenteTask.getHexaColor() returns an empty string. Tried debugging it, like: tracing the value that gets passed into the method?

Comment: @GhostCat I tried debugging it, and the value that i see there is the correct string... i don't know why it still pass me that error

Comment: Are you sure you went through every item in the adapter? It's definitely trying to parse a string that is empty. Maybe add log output so you don't have to step through every single item.

Comment: Are you setting breakpoints inside getView()? You should verify the Task item right before the parse call.

Comment: Pull the presenteTask.getHexaColor() out of the parseColor call and set the returned value. Then set a conditional breakpoint or add an if statement, to check the String contents, for debugging.

It will be easier to see if every iteration is returning a valid string.

Comment: @Reger05 If I do something like: String Hexa = presenteTask.getHexaColor(); Place a breakpoint on that line, The value inside Hexa is the correct value.

Comment: @Vitorlsa Place a conditional breakpoint 
if(Hexa.isEmpty())

If your IDE doesn't support conditional breakpoints, simply add an if statement to your code with the breakpoint set inside. This will only break if the string is empty finding the bug (length=0).

As others have stated, the iteration you are seeing this on may be correct. It may be breaking during another iteration. 

If you step through after checking the value in the debugger and it still throws an exception you can try stepping into EditText::setBackgroundColor and see if the correct value is present.

Comment: @Reger05 did that! And in fact it is empty, but i don't understand why! I still don't know what i should do... hehehe. But thank you very much! To everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `getView()` of `TaskAdapter` one of your `taskData` item return empty `hexaColor` during execution of `presenteTask.getHexaColor()`. Try below code, it will stop your application being force closed and you will get the position of item causing `exception` inside `catch`.

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
    View listItem = convertView;
    if(listItem == null)
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(sContext).inflate(R.layout.item_tasks, parent,false);

    try {
        final Tasks presenteTask = taskData.get(position);
        TextView taskTitle = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.tasksTitle);
        taskTitle.setText(presenteTask.getTitle());
        EditText taskColor = (EditText) listItem.findViewById(R.id.taskColor);
        taskColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(presenteTask.getHexaColor()));
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.v(TasksAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "Exception at: " + position);
    }

    return listItem;
}
```

Comment: If I use a try catch just for the "taskColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(presenteTask.getHexaColor()));" part it works! I don't know why but it works! And it doesn't even go inside the catch. Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest avoiding adding in try/catch of a generic exception to control your program flow as such. 

If you expect conditions where the hex color may be empty then handle it appropriately by adding in logic to check for this. Either don't set the background color or set the background color to a default color.

Adding a try/catch of a generic exception will cause you to swallow other exception that may actually be a problem for your program and will become difficult to debug, not to mention you are now cluttering your logs with an expected scenario (an empty hex string).

Comment: @Reger05 thank you man! I handled it the way you told me and it looks better, but now i can't get buttons to work... in every other adapter i have for my listviews i have buttons that works fine, but in this one everything seems like a problem. Thank you again for your tips!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is your problem

```
taskColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(presenteTask.getHexaColor()));
```

Not sure what is **presenteTask.getHexaColor()** returning, but as I read from your comments, you say that is a valid string. You need to specify exactly what is the format of your color string.

*For example three digit color strings are not supported by Color.parseColor().* You can look at **Android Platform API documentation** and read about the Color class. 
Another information from the documentation:

> Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB

Make sure you use the correct color string format.